# Ruby. (condition) ? return : next .Returning error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

```
(1<2) ? return : next
```

> dos.rb: dos.rb:74: Invalid next (SyntaxError)

What is the correct way to tell ruby to 'continue' in this context .

if 1 is less than 2, leave the function, else keep going

Comment: It will help fix your issue if you will send the whole loop method!

Comment: `return if  i < 2` or `if i < 2; return; end`. (..`if 1 < 2` is not the best example, since its always `true`).

Answer (score 5):

You can just say:

```
return if (1 < 2)
```

You don't have to tell Ruby to "keep going" -- that's what it'll do if it doesn't return from the function!

Answer (score 4):

`return` returns from a method or lambda, `next` returns from a block. There is neither a method nor a lambda nor a block in your code, therefore neither `return` nor `next` are valid in your code.

Comment: Although top-level `return` exists in newer Ruby versions.

Answer (score 2):

Just use if instead of a ternary, and be sure you are in a context (such as a loop) where `next` is valid.